# Select from 30 tables in MySql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I have a database that has a table per day. I need to query the last 30 days of data which means that I need to do a select statement across 30 tables.

This is in php and the tables are named like so;

`table_01_03_13`
`table_02_03_13`
`table_03_03_13`
`table_04_03_13`

`etc...`

My question is what is the best way to query these tables bearing in mind that they are dates, would I do a loop through the last 30 days to create me query string? which would give me a string like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_01_03_13, table_02_03_13, table_03_03_13, table_04_03_13....
```

or is there an SQL function to do this quicker and easier?

The only reason there is a table a day, is due to the fact that there are 40,000 records added to the DB daily.

Comment: table per day! well fix that first

Comment: Your database structure needs to be reworked.

Comment: Terrible design! A table can hold more than 40k rows in it and creating a new table everyday is going to be a nightmare to work with.  Please fix your design.

Comment: uh, why not a single table with a `day` field?

Comment: MySQL tables can be as big as 64 terabytes: [The maximum tablespace size is four billion database pages (64TB). This is also the maximum size for a table.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Comment: 14,600,000 may, or may not be a lot of data. I'd encourage the responsible parties to really understand their data first, and then go back and model it properly so that access and retrieval can be optimized.

Comment: i have a table for collecting logs on a web site with more than 5k users in 8 hours per day and it collect many more than 40k rows of events on any page per hour, simply with date and time of events.

Answer (score 7):

Why not a structure like:

```
create table yourtable (
   id int,
   date_of_event timestamp
   ...
);
```

and then you can simply have

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE date_of_event = '2013-04-10'
```

or even by particular days:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE YEAR(date_of_event) < 2013
   AND DAY(date_of_event) = 13

// fetch all the events that occured on 'day 13' or any month in the previous years.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $tables = '';
    $daysInMonth = 30; // untrue, just an example..
    for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++)
    {
        if(strlen($i) < 2) $i = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if($i===$daysInMonth) $tables .= 'table_' . $i . '_03_13';
        else $tables .= 'table_' . $i . '_03_13, ';
    }
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tables;
    echo $query;
?>
```

output:

```
SELECT * FROM table_01_03_13, table_02_03_13, table_03_03_13, table_04_03_13, table_05_03_13, table_06_03_13, table_07_03_13, table_08_03_13, table_09_03_13, table_10_03_13, table_11_03_13, table_12_03_13, table_13_03_13, table_14_03_13, table_15_03_13, table_16_03_13, table_17_03_13, table_18_03_13, table_19_03_13, table_20_03_13, table_21_03_13, table_22_03_13, table_23_03_13, table_24_03_13, table_25_03_13, table_26_03_13, table_27_03_13, table_28_03_13, table_29_03_13, table_30_03_13
```

Answer (score -1):

Collect dates into array like "table_d_m_y", then
select * from '.implode($tables).'

---

**EDIT by Kolink to add some code to this prose:**

Something along these lines:

```
$tables = Array();
for( $i=0; $i<30; $i++) $tables[] = "table_".date("d_m_y",strtotime("-".$i." days"));
query("SELECT * FROM ".implode(",",$tables));
```